# Want to display specific date records from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

Hi Friends I have to Display records from db using stored procedure.

To display the records from one date to another date I used :

```
and Tbl_GDS_Request.RequestedDate between '''+ convert(varchar(20),@p_FromDate) + ''' 
and  ''' + convert(varchar(20), @p_ToDate) + ''''
```

but if I want to display only `fromdate` records (ie only records in 2013/11/07 date) or to date Records, ie only records in `2013/11/07` date.

What should I do to display the records of single date?

please help me to fix it.

Comment: Use `=` instead of `between`. But what is the data type of `Tbl_GDS_Request.RequestedDate` is it a `date` or `varchar`?

Comment: it's a datetime datatype

Comment: You shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types _especially_ [on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  It also looks like you're creating the query by string concatenation, which opens you up to SQL Injection; you should be using prepared statements, which will _also_ enable you to use actual date/time types - your current method is _not_ safe in all instances.  For better question clarity, what are your anticipated incoming parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Create for each statement an OR selection.
this would look like the following. (Code not tested)

```
CREATE PROC Procname
(
 @date1 datetime IS NULL,
 @date2 datetime IS NULL
)
AS
select 
 *
from 
 atable a
where 
 --when both dates are filled in
 (@date1 is not NULL 
  AND @date2 is not NULL 
  AND a.date >= @date1 
  AND a.date <= @date2)
 OR
 --when only todate is filled in
 (@date1 is NULL 
  AND @date2 is not NULL 
  AND a.date <= @date2)
 OR
 -- when only fromdate is filled in
 (@date1 is not NULL 
  AND @date2 is NULL 
  AND a.date >= @date1)
```